# Couldn't remove a directory, already tried rmdir -rf

Tags: terminal, rm

I kept on trying to remove a folder in the server, but I kept on getting a same error. Please help me. I used this post as a reference

https://askubuntu.com/questions/217893/how-to-delete-a-non-empty-directory-in-terminal

```
xxxxxxx@sflogin0$ cd TESTS/
xxxxxxx@sflogin0$ ls
run    test   trail
xxxxxxx@sflogin0$ rmdir -rf test/
rmdir: illegal option -- r
rmdir: illegal option -- f
Usage: rmdir [-ps] dirname ...
xxxxxxx@sflogin0$ ls
run    test   trail
xxxxxxx@sflogin0$ rmdir -pr test/
rmdir: illegal option -- r
Usage: rmdir [-ps] dirname ...
xxxxxxx@sflogin0$ rmdir -ps test/
xxxxxxx@sflogin0$ ls
run    test   trail
xxxxxxx@sflogin0$ rmdir -f test/
rmdir: illegal option -- f
Usage: rmdir [-ps] dirname ...
xxxxxxx@sflogin0$
```

Comment: Why not just `rm -rf test`?

Comment: I get this error:: `rm: Unable to remove directory test//test: File exists
rm: Unable to remove directory test/: File exists`

Comment: Is `test` a mountpoint?

Comment: not sure. there is no file in terminal(Mobaxterm) window, but folder view there are two files from server host (.nfs27F96 and .nfs37F96)

Comment: or are one of the files in test executing or open for editing at the moment? what does ls -al on the directory show?

Comment: Also I tried to chmod 777

Comment: You can check running `mount`. If the `test` full path appears in the list, it is a mountpoint and it would explain why you can't delete it.

Comment: it says `mount: Mount point cannot be determined`, what is mount?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Instead of tring to delete it from Mobaxterminal, I used the server site to delete it. Worked like a charm.